# PHP Oracle OCI8 query to keep/handle null columns in array

Tags: php, sql, arrays, oracle, nvl

I have the below sql query.. in which I'm mapping the contents to a kendo front-end table..

```
$sql = "SELECT big_id, fac_ident, lg_name, basic_tp, catc_vd, address, assoc_city, latitude, longitude, assoc_cnty, assoc_st, time_zone, faa_reg, ato_sa, ato_td, fema_reg, ops_hrs, prim_ph, atc_level, tower_type, manager, sat_phone_num, td_mgr, to_dist, tod_mgr, stof_fac, ops_status, crt_rl FROM myCoolApp.big_id";
```

The problem is.. columns that are not finding any associated value in the DB, is not returning any value back, and alas just completely omitted from the response array.. i.e. in `ops_hrs` above no value is found, so it's completely omitted from my array - I need it to still exist, just be blank.

I would like the response to still display the column in the array even when it's value is *empty*; ideally just adding a blank space `" "` or `'N/A'` even. As I do not want the null column to be dropped in my array and front-end.

The rest of my PHP/sql...

```
        $stid = oci_parse($this->db, $sql);
        oci_execute($stid); 
            
        $myData = array();

        while ($list = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC)) {
            array_push($myData, $list);
        }
    
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo "{\"data\":" .json_encode($myData). "}";
```

What am I missing here? I need to handle it programmatically with PHP/sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `OCI_RETURN_NULLS`:

```
while ($list = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
    array_push($myData, $list);
}
```

See the [PHP OCI8 `oci_fetch_array` documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-fetch-array.php).

Answer (score 0):

As of SQL (and Oracle), you could use the `NVL` function which returns column value if it exists, or its "substitute" if it does not.

For example, in this query `comm` column's value is `NULL`:

```
SQL> select ename, comm from emp where empno = 7369;

ENAME            COMM
---------- ----------
SMITH
```

You'd then

```
SQL> select nvl(ename, 'N/A') as ename,
  2         nvl(comm , 0    ) as comm
  3  from emp
  4  where empno = 7369;

ENAME            COMM
---------- ----------
SMITH               0

SQL>
```

Pay attention to column's datatype. If it is a string, `NVL` should return a string as well (such as `'N/A'`); if it is a number, let it return a number (such as `0`), etc.

There's no "universal" way to do it, so you'll have to apply `NVL` to all columns you're selecting.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I have to do it programmatically via PHP/sql

Comment: I don't speak PHP, but - wouldn't your query then just be e.g. `$sql = "SELECT nvl(big_id, -1) as big_id, nvl(fac_ident, 'N/A') as fac_ident, ... FROM your_table ...`?

Comment: I have never used nvl, bit of a oracle noob, but will give that a run, why the '-1'?

Comment: Pick any value you want, this is just an example. I presumed that BIG_ID column's datatype is NUMBER, so I chose NVL to return a number: -1 if BIG_ID column is empty. You can return anything, 9999, -3009, 1E15 ...